# Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia-352 opencl support

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

Is OpenCL supported for nvidia-352 driver package in Ubuntu 14.04. I have Asus Zenbook UX303UB with GeForce 940M, so only latest nvidia-352 driver works, but I can't get OpenCL working. First, ocd loader seems to be missing, i.e. no libOpenCL.so if you install all the available 352 opencl related packages. But even if you symlink it from libOpenCL.so.1 or use generic loader, then no platforms are detected.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the installation of `nvidia-opencl-icd-352` should do the work. You'll have a file name `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd` which contains the following information `libnvidia-opencl.so.1`. Nevertheless, you should be sure that the kernel module `nvidia_352_uvm` is loaded, when you want to run an **opencl** or **cuda** application.

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidia_352_uvm
$ sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm c 249 0 # read comment below
```

*Use the second command **only if** the first command doesn't generate the /dev/nvidia-uvm node.*

Sometimes also you'll need to run a program as root (not all the times though). For example `sudo clinfo` and then you'll be able to run it without root permissions.

Comment: OCD is installed, loader - libOpenCL.so is not installed. Thanks, I'll check that.